# Search at hash table at several keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I created a hash table. My task is to enter quantity of pairs  and quantity of keys. Then enter pairs and keys. And show result. I can show result at one key, but how I can show result at several keys at the same time?

For example if I enter pairs:

43 gh

8 mn

90 as

and keys:

43

90

The result must be:

gh

as

This is my code

Comment: While questions about homework are not a problem by themselves, you should not just dump the assignment into the question box. There are too many ways to solve a problem like this to make it a good fit for this Q/A format. Instead, try yourself and when you get stuck, ask a *specific* question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the query keys in a vector. Then, when its time to deliver the results, loop through your vector of queries and retrieve the information and print line by line.

Comment: I have not studied the vectors. whether it is possible to use an array?

Comment: Absolutely.  A vector is an array that can do extra stuff, but if you haven't gotten to vectors yet, an array would be just fine.